# react native Flatlist navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-flatlist

I m getting error 
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined. I don't understand how to pass navigation component into each child so when a user presses an item it can navigate to employeeEdit component using React Navigation. i am newbie sorry if this is obvious.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//import { R } from 'ramda';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { employeesFetch } from '../actions';
import { HeaderButton } from './common';
import ListEmployee from './ListEmployee';


class EmployeeList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate('employeeCreate')}>
        Add
      </HeaderButton>
    )
  });

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.employeesFetch();
  }

  keyExtractor(item) {
    return item.uid;
  }
  renderItem({ item }) {
    return <ListEmployee employee={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
      data={this.props.employees}
      renderItem={this.renderItem} // Only for test
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      navigation={this.props.navigation}
      />
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => ({ ...val, uid }));
  return { employees };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeesFetch })(EmployeeList);
```

Here's the code for ListEmployee

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common';

class ListEmployee extends Component {

  render() {
  const { employee } = this.props;
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  const { textStyle } = styles;
  const { name } = this.props.employee;
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigate('employeeEdit', { employee })}>
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{name}</Text>
          </CardSection>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

/**
 second argument in connect does 2 things. 1.  dispatches all actions creators
return action objects to the store to be used by reducers; 2. creates props
of action creators to be used by components
**/
export default ListEmployee;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15,
  }
});
```

Comment: can you include your code that passes the navigation prop to `EmployeeList` (EG its parent component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your renderItem method, you can manage what happens when the user presses one an item of your FlatList:

```
renderItem({ item }) {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.navigator.push({id: 'employeeEdit'})}} >
        <ListEmployee employee={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Hope it help you!

Answer (score 6):

This is one ES6 common pitfall. Don't worry my friend, you only have to learn it once to avoid them all over again.

Long story short, when you declare a method inside React Component, make it arrow function

So, change from this.

`renderItem({ item }) {`

to this

`renderItem = ({ item }) => {`

That should solve your problem, for some inconvenient reason, you can only access "this" if you declare your method as an arrow function, but not with normal declaration.

In your case, since renderItem is not an arrow function, "this" is not referred to the react component, therefore "this.props" is likely to be undefined, that is why it gave you this error `Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined` since

`this.props.navigation = (undefined).navigation`

Comment: In my case the problem was in the function the is called when a list item get pressed.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation sample

here VendorList is the structure rendered

```
<FlatList
            numColumns={6}
            data={state.vendoreList}
            keyExtractor={(data) => data.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Home1")} >
             <VendorList item={item} />
             </TouchableOpacity>
             }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in ListEmployee

const {**navigation**}= this.props.navigation;

this use

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => **navigation.navigate**('employeeEdit', { employee })}>

just need to modification on those two lines, i make text bold what changes you need to do