# Component function can't recognize this operator in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Basically, I want to call function (class method) from inside the functionComponent in react-native. Only way i can do it by passing as a props as shown in example B (image with debugging info). I want to try it like in example A (image with debugging info); Is there some way to achieve that (not using props)? Or there is whole another way to do it, any suggestion or tips or tricks would be nice. Or am i missing something.

*Code for Example A.*

```
//Example A
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class RegisterScreen extends React.Component{
    state = { message: "state message"};

    openDialog(){
        alert("hello..");
    }

    funcComponent({text}){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.state.message);

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{text}</Text>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.openDialog()} title="Open"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <this.funcComponent text="hello from component." />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[Example A Debugging Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzwKY.png)

*Code for Example B*

```
//Example B
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class RegisterScreen extends React.Component{
    state = { message: "state message"};

    openDialog(){
        alert("hello..");
    }

    funcComponent({text, openDialog, context}){
        console.log(context);
        console.log(context.state.message);
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{text}</Text>
                <Button onPress={()=> openDialog()} title="Open"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <this.funcComponent text="hello from component." openDialog={this.openDialog} context={this} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[Example B Debugging Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRYly.png)

***Edit:***
Ok, basically the problem is with the component, we can't just use "this" operator inside the **functioncomponent** coz we are using in the `<this.funcComponent>` (in Example A) that is why we need to pass this operator as props (which is done in Example B). In **Example A** "this" operator is **out of the scope** so that is why we need to pass as props.

Hope this is helpful to other who is facing this problem.

## **Edit 2: Solution for what i looking for**

I found new solution for using "this" operator inside method or function, to use this operator we need to make arrow function, which makes the function inside the scope of the class.

*(Basically it's a ES6 pitfall)* reference: @doppio [react native Flatlist navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116601/react-native-flatlist-navigation)

*Code for Example C*

```
//Example C
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class RegisterScreen extends React.Component{
    state = { message: "i m state message"};

    openDialog(){
        alert("hello..");
    }

    funcComponent=({text}) => {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.state.message);

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{text}</Text>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.openDialog()} title="Open"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <this.funcComponent text="hello from component." />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The error in the first image because there will be no scope of "this" you need pass "this" from your functional component

Comment: We can use "this" operator in other type of function right why can't we use in functionComponent ??

Comment: Check this docs it might help you https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

Comment: Thanks mate love the article. I guess i missed it.

Comment: Hope you got it now.